# Delete the single existing record in table OR delete all records except latest?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I'm trying to figure out a way to check for the count of records in a table, and:

- if it's equal to 1, then just delete that one record,
- if it's greater than 1, then delete all except the latest record.

```sql
create schema if not exists bv;
create table bv.profile (id bigint primary key, user_id bigint not null);

insert into bv.profile values(2, 100), (1, 101), (3, 100);
```

I can obviously do this in two queries on my backend like so:

```sql
select count(*) from bv.profile where user_id = $1;
-- if count == 1
delete from bv.profile where user_id = $1
-- else if count > 1
delete from bv.profile
where id not in (
  select id
  from bv.profile
  order by id desc
  limit 1
)
and user_id = $1
```

Is there any way to get this to work in one query though?

After playing around, I came up with this:

```sql
delete from bv.profile
where user_id = $1 
and id not in (
  select max(id) from bv.profile
  where user_id = $1
  group by user_id
    having count(*) > 1
);
```

Not sure how performant this will be, though.

Comment: Your solution looks ok - just remember to add an index. It performs way better than [the alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77894917/5298879): here's [yours against 300k rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/l2YBiplX), and [here's the other one losing](https://dbfiddle.uk/kqLJr93j) in both single and bulk delete. Also, that env could accommodate a test [with your approach on 500k rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/KNYx4QXU), while [the other one ran out of memory at 400k](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ye0dBhtk).

Comment: I think unless someone comes around and beats your score in the tests above, a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) would be more than justified.

Answer (score 0):

See example

```
delete from profile
  using (
select *
  ,count(*)over(partition by user_id) cnt
  ,row_number()over(partition by user_id order by id desc) rn
from profile) t 
where t.id=profile.id and (cnt=1 or rn>1)
```

Assuming that max(id) - last row - order by id desc.

Subquery output is

| id | user_id | cnt | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 100 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 101 | 1 | 1 |

Table `profile` after query execution

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 100 |